# How do I get a nicely-formatted lmfit fit_report into Excel?

Tags: python, excel

I'm using lmfit to fit my data to a model equation.

I'm  using pandas.DataFrame.to_excel to write the initial guesses, param hints, and best values to an Excel spreadsheet, for possible later use.

I'm also writing the fit report to the spreadsheet, as shown below ["results" is the output of lmfit's model.fit(), while "bit_id" is the experimental unit whose data I'm trying to fit.]

```
fit_report_string = results.fit_report()
temp_dict5 = {'fit_report': fit_report_string}
temp_df5 = pd.DataFrame(data=temp_dict5, index=np.array([0]))
temp_df5.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=bit_id + ' fit_report')
```

I get the fit report in the spreadsheet but it all goes into one cell, which makes it hard to read.

I'd like something that is nicely-formatted, similar to what I get when I print the fit report.

I'm agnostic as to exactly how that happens - the entire fit report could be in one properly-sized cell, or each line of the fit report could be in a separate cell.

I'm also agnostic as to whether this is done using pandas or something else.  (Although if I use something other than pandas, I suspect I'd need to make an Excel writer for that other module.)

I've discovered that if I double-click the spreadsheet cell containing the fit report, then change the column width to 42 and the row height to 255, I get the nicely-formatted report but I can't figure out how to do that programmatically.

Suggestions?

Clarification: I can use openpyxl to change the cell's width and height but I can't figure out how to programmatically simulate the double-click's action of editing the cell.

Comment: M Newville's suggestion of PyBroom might be a way of side-stepping my problem.  It doesn't solve the question I asked (getting a nicely-formatted fit report in Excel) but it might solve the higher-level question of "How do I get a readable version of the fit report information into Excel?"  I'll have to see about process of getting PyBroom installed locally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be that the `pybroom` project does enough of what you are looking for.  See https://github.com/tritemio/pybroom

In general, I think many other people would be interested in better sorting and viewing of fit results using a Dataframe and or spreadsheet-like layout. It is probably worth trying to add this to `lmfit`.